# HTML and CSS, align 2 buttons horizontally without losing the form action

Tags: html, css, forms, button

[image]

Each of these two buttons call an external php page.  The way both of them display on the page are vertically align each other.  How can I make **horizontally** **align** each other and of course **without losing the form action**.? See screenshot

Code Below and thank you so much.

```
<form action="reboot.php" method="get">
  <button class="button button3" type="submit">Server Reboot</button>
</form>

<form action="shutdown.php" method="get">
  <button class="button button3" type="submit">Server Shutdown</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it !

```
<div class="form-wrapper">
<form action="reboot.php" method="get">
  <button class="button button3" type="submit">Server Reboot</button>
</form>

<form action="shutdown.php" method="get">
  <button class="button button3" type="submit">Server Shutdown</button>
</form>
</div>
```

```
.form-wrapper{
    display: flex;
}
```

`display: flex` in CSS aligns all of its containg items horizonally.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to apply "display: inline" on both buttons.

```
<form action="reboot.php" method="get" class="inline">
  <button class="button button3" type="submit">Server Reboot</button>
</form>

<form action="shutdown.php" method="get" class="inline">
  <button class="button button3" type="submit">Server Shutdown</button>
</form>
```

```
.inline {
    display: inline;
}
```